# Rails keeps increasing memory steadily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm using rails 2.3.2 with ruby 1.8.7 and nginx passenger. This application is a RESTful API which serves around 700 requests per minute. Everything goes fine except the memory consumed is growing from 55 Mb to 120 Mb (1 day after).

Do I have to restart those instances every week? I wonder other people facing this problem as well? Or something wrong with this application?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need found where is you memory leak. After this first day, the memory still growing or stabilize ?

Comment: Very small increment on each day after the first day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [REE (Ruby Enterprise Edition)](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) instead of ruby 1.8.7.

It uses 33% less memory on average, and is 100% compatible with 1.8.7. 
Without looking at the code, it sounds like a garbage collection problem, which [REE](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) + passenger might be able to solve.

From what I've heard, ruby 1.9.2 has a lot of the same enhancements, but switching an app over to run on [REE](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) would probably be a lot easier than upgrading to 1.9.2.

Comment: Does most rails apps increase memory all the time like this?

Comment: I don't think so. But then again, you are using Rails 2.3.2, which is quite dated now. Its impossible to say what the problem is without looking at code, so theres only 2 suggestions I could give: Use REE, or upgrade to Rails 2.3.8 (which should be quite painless)